# Extract JSON object inside JSON object via php

Tags: php, json

I have JSON data as shown:

```
{
    "15": {
        "nid": "15",
        "status": "1",
        "created": "1352652530",
        "changed": "1353780901",
        "title": "some data",
        "type": "some data",
        "tracking_url": {
            "10": {
                "affiliate": "OMG",
                "url_part1": "some data"
            }
        },
        "primary_category": "Travel",
        "active_affiliate": "OMG"
    },
    "16": {
        "nid": "16",
        "status": "1",
        "created": "1352652530",
        "changed": "1353780901",
        "title": "some data",
        "type": "some data",
        "tracking_url": {
            "11": {
                "affiliate": "OMG",
                "url_part1": "some data"
            }
        },
        "primary_category": "Travel",
        "active_affiliate": "OMG"
    }
}
```

I can decode the JSON successfully using this:

```
$response = json_decode($p, true);
```

Now I have to pull the **url_part1** and **affiliate** values from `$response` (extract elements inside **tracking_url**), which I am unable to do.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON text. Please show us a **correct** representative example.

Comment: Two curly braces in a row? That's not valid JSON... You should be getting `false`.

Comment: @MattBall : have Edited the question and included the link for original the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the JSON structure in `$p` actually looks like this:

```
"16": {
    "nid":"16",

    "tracking_url": {
        "10": {
            "affiliate":"OMG",
            "url_part1":"some data"
        }
    }

},
```

You can access the url_part1 and affiliate with the following

```
$response = json_decode($p, true);

$urlPart = array();
$affiliate = array();

foreach ($response as $nid => $data) {
    $urlPart[$nid]   = $data['tracking_url']['10']['url_part1'];
    $affiliate[$nid] = $data['tracking_url']['10']['affiliate'];
}
```

This is just an example of how to access the data, you can write to any variable you need as applicable.

Comment: what is the purpose of `$nid => $data` ??

Comment: `$nid` will get the name of the JSON object, ie `"16": { ... },` then `$data` will get the data assigned to that object.